# sendToURL doesn't send to URL

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache, http

I edited the question as suggested in meta.stackoverflow to improve the quality of my question for better understanding :))

I am using phpbb 3 and just downloaded a MOD called Proxy Revealer which primarly used to detect and ban IP Addresses and the following attached code is a part of the MOD, as you can see the ActionScript uses sendToURL method to pass flash variables to PHP side which uses the _GET method to obtain values but the problem is that the values always come as NULL, I did some research using burpsuite and seen the values in the client's header request but was never executed in the URL bar or even disclosed that's why they came as NULL

- URL = example.com/index.php
- Request Header = index.php?value=3424124&another=32412342

How can I get those values in PHP variables, thanks for taking the time to read my message and have a nice day :))

```
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.errors.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.sendToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.XMLSocket;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.xml.*;

// Retrieve passed FlashVars
var dhost:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.dhost;
var dport:Number = root.loaderInfo.parameters.dport;
var flash_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.flash_url;
var ip:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.ip;
var extra:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.extra;
var user_agent:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.user_agent;

// Retrieve policy file from our XMLSocket server to allow socket connections
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + dhost + ":" + dport);

// Get Flash Player version
var version:String = Capabilities.version;

// Our probe.php URL and the query string concatenated
var myURL:String = flash_url + "?mode=flash&ip=" + ip + "&extra=" + extra;
myURL += "&version=" + escape(version) + "&user_agent=" + escape(user_agent);

// Socket connection code
var sock:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();

sock.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
sock.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler);

sock.connect(dhost,dport);

function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
    var xmlRequest:String = "<data><request>getmyip</request></data>";
    sock.send(new XML(xmlRequest));
}

function dataHandler(event:DataEvent):void {
    var myXML:XML = new XML(event.data);
    var myIP:String = myXML.ip[0];
    myURL += "&xml_ip=" + myIP;
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myURL);
    sendToURL(request);
    sock.close();
}
```

Comment: after modification, it's NOT @animuson

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php ? Seems to only work with some Apache setups though.

Comment: never worked with me :(

Comment: Works for me on my laptop but not on my main server... My laptop is running PHP 5.4.6, and I'm not sure if it's using mod_php or FastCGI, but my server is running PHP 5.3.3 and certainly using FastCGI. Docs say it only became available under FastCGI in 5.4.0.

Which version of PHP are you running, and do you know if you're using FastCGI or mod_php?

Comment: I am using php 5.1.6 with FastCGI as I setup my own server :))

Comment: Ah, yes, then it appears getallheaders() won't help you with PHP 5.1.6 in FastCGI. =\

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if(function_exists('headers_list')){
    $header = "Headers: ";
    foreach (headers_list() as $name => $value) {
        $header .= "$value ";
    }
}
```

or try

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

Comment: it only returns the address before ?